# Show popups only once when user logged in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4, popup

I am working with mvc4. In my layout page , i have a popup that shows only when user is logged in.

```
  @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    { 
      <div class="pop-suggest popup_window">            
         <div class="invite-add">    
           <a id="popupBoxCloseAd" class="close-popup">X</a>        
           <h4 class="invite-tit">"Earn more points, Get more products!!!"</h4>
           <div> Invite Friends</div>
        </div>            
    </div>
    }
```

for close This popup I use the following jquery,

```
 $('.close-popup').click(function () {
    close_popup();
 });
 function close_popup() {      
    $('.popup_window').fadeOut(500);       
  }
```

my problem is that, after login, this popup will arrive in every page refresh. How can i change this code to popup this div shows only when user is login and after close it will not come.

Comment: how you are opening this popup??

Comment: @Kartikeya: When page loading and user is authenticated , this popup is shown

Comment: popup opens automatically or you have written some code to open popup on document ready??

Comment: @Kartikeya:  i am not wirting any code in   document ready for open this,this div is in my html layout page

Comment: this is not possible somewhere in your layout document ready you will be triggering popup to open or you must be intializing popup on document ready in layout page...just check carefully..

Answer (score 1):

In my opionion you can create cookie when user log in with some kind of flag and destroy cookie on log out. I was doing something similar in my apps and works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ViewData:

```
    ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel vmodel) 
    {  
 if (GetAuthenticationResult(vmodel.UserName, vmodel.Password))
        {
            ViewData["AuthPassed"] = true;
            //.... other code   
        } 
     //... other code 
    }
```

And then make your ViewData to be checked in Layout for non-null equality.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a flag to the session:

```
@{       
   if (Session["isAlreadyDisplayed"] == null) {
      ... your code ...
   }
   else {
      Session["isAlreadyDisplayed"] = true;
   }    
}
```

And don't forget to remove the session variable each time user logged in.

```
 Session.Remove("isAlreadyDisplayed");
```